# best way to remove the first word in a string in Java

Tags: java, string, performance

What is the fastest way of getting rid off the first token in a string? So far, I've tried this:

```
String parentStringValue = this.stringValue.split(" ", 2)[1];
```

and it's extremely memory and speed inefficient (when repeated millions of times for 15 word long strings). Suppose the string is made of tokens separated by spaces.

Comment: did u use substring? and the question is not clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### StringBuilder vs `substring( x )` vs `split( x )` vs Regex

**Answer Edited : Major Flaws Corrected**

After correcting for some fairly major flaws in my benchmarking (as pointed out by Jay Askren in the comments). The `StringBuilder` method came out as the fastest by a significant margin (although this assumes that the `StringBuilder` objects were pre-created), with substring coming out in second place. `split()` came out second to last at 10x slower than the `StringBuilder` method.

```
  ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<StringBuilder> stringBuilders = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) strings.add("Remove the word remove from String "+i);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) stringBuilders.add(new StringBuilder(i+" Remove the word remove from String "+i));
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s");

  // StringBuilder method
  before = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
      for(StringBuilder s : stringBuilders){
          s.delete(0, s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
      }
  }
  after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
  System.out.println("StringBuilder Method Took "+after);

  // Substring method
  before = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
      for(String s : strings){
          String newvalue = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
      }
  }
  after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
  System.out.println("Substring Method Took "+after); 

  //Split method
  before = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
      for(String s : strings){
          String newvalue = s.split(" ", 2)[1];
          System.out.print("");
      }
  }
  after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
  System.out.println("Your Method Took "+after);

  // Regex method
  before = System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++){
      for(String s : strings){
          String newvalue = pattern.matcher(s).replaceFirst("");
      }
  }
  after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
  System.out.println("Regex Method Took "+after);
```

I ran the above in random orders, after a warm up, in succession taking averages, increased the number of operations from 5 million to 30 million, and ran each ten times before moving on to the next. Either way the order of fastest to slowest stayed the same. Below is some sample output from the code above;

```
StringBuilder Method Took 203
Substring Method Took 588
Split Method Took 1833
Regex Method Took 2517
```

It is worth mentioning that calling `split()` with a `String` with a length greater than 1 simply uses Regex in its implementation and so there should be no difference between using `split()` and a `Pattern` object.

Comment: There are quite a few mistakes in this code.  One of the big ones is that you are comparing apples and oranges.  For instance, the first time you collect is (after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before).  The remaining times you calculate time is (after = System.currentTimeMillis() - after) which includes printing stuff out.  If you fix that, the substring method is 5 times faster on my machine.  Also you never create the object stringBuilders.  Not to mention, before and after do not have types.  Plus, it is generally good to run each test 5 or 10 times so you can see the outliers.

Comment: Another problem: The regex method compiles the regex every time. This is not how fast code should be made. And 5000 iterations times 1000 string is probably not enough. For measuring time, I'd suggest `System.nanoTime` - it's more precise and guaranteed to be monotonic.

Comment: Agreed @maaartinus.  The alternative to using nano time is to use many more interations.  I'd recommend at least 100,000 repetitions for this test.    It's not a very good performance benchmark if it only takes half a second.  You want to run it longer so the JIT at least has a chance to kick in.

Comment: @Rudi I improved upon your benchmark in another answer.  Split is 5 times slower than the fastest methods for doing this.

Comment: Every method returns String object except for StringBuilder where you should call toString() to make them even.

Comment: @headsvk - I would argue you don't want to make them even, given that you wont always need a `String` returned immediately. Your saving time in at least those circumstances.

Comment: Could we add a few newlines between sections to make it clearer where the divisions are?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes - Sure. I added a few newlines in, and there are also the comments between sections.

Answer (score 5):

No need to split and create array, Just use substring

```
String str="I want to remove I";
String parentStringValue = str.substring(str.indexOf(" ")+1);
System.out.println(parentStringValue);
```

Out put:

```
want to remove I
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of `String.substring` and `String.indexOf` for this.

Something along the lines of:

```
// TODO check indexOf does not return -1
this.stringValue.substring(this.stringValue.indexOf(" ") + 1)
```

Comment: It seems to be slower that the current way I am doing it.

Comment: @user3639557 you'll have to provide more information than "it's slow" to get any further help. I.e. stack traces, specs on sizes, etc. This is almost guaranteed to be faster than splitting the whole `String` into an array.

Comment: It's not slower, it provides almost the same speed (a few miliseconds faster). Processing 30000 lines takes the same amount of time.

Comment: @user3639557 - See my other comment. If your outputting each String then its your printing to the screen which is limiting the speed of your process.

Comment: This is about 5 times faster than the original according to my tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  String s = "This is a test";

  System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("\\w+\\s", ""));
```

Comment: It's still slow. And it seems to be worse than the current way I am doing this.

Comment: @user3639557 Why you think it is slow?

Comment: well I can see how fast I am iterating over the lines in the file. This operation is being done on each line. and I am generating and output after every 10000 lines.

Comment: I have tried it with a loop without reading a file and i have 10000 records in 405 ms. I think that is not slow.

Comment: @user3639557 - If your watching it, then it's your System.out.println() statements that are slowing your process. Printing to the screen really very slow compared to most processes. Remove it and just output the beginning and ending times.

Comment: I agree that printing slows down the execution, but this is not the case here as I am comparing different ways of removing the first word and not changing anything else in the code.

Comment: Whithout printing every line it speeds up to 150 ms. I think in your case the reading and writing the file takes the time.

Comment: @user3639557 - I think your over-estimating the reliability of your benchmarks, especially by including print() statements **during** your logic. Have a quick read of [this.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/513259/2182928)

Comment: Can't I say this: printing will have the same amount of overhead?

Comment: I think file io has more overhead then printing in a console.

Comment: s.replaceFirst has to compile a regular expression and then run the regular expression everytime it runs.  Regular expressions are often slower than just looping through the characters in the string and checking if the character is a specific character.  Then compiling the expression every time just makes it that much slower.  If you are going to use a regular expression, at least compile it first outside of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use StringBuffer or StringBuilder when doing string operation so that it won't leaving behind a lot of new unused objects and cause memory inefficient since repeated millions of times as you mentioned

Comment: I don't see how using StringBuilder will fit to this problem?

Comment: How about declare "this.stringValue" as StringBuilder instead of String, and use its delete method to get rid off the first token in that StringBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Rudi's benchmark had quite a few problems including unfairly and incorrectly favoring the split method. So I took his benchmark and improved upon it.  If by chance you have a bunch of StringBuilders, the StringBuilder approach is slightly faster but if you need to convert them from strings first, it is quite slow.  The substring approach is the next fastest and the one you should use if you have strings and not string builders.  CommonsLang is the next fastest, and both the substring method and CommonsLang method are 4 to 5 times faster than using split.  String.replaceFirst() uses regular expressions and is very slow because it needs to compile the regular expression every time it runs which doubles the time to run.  Even without the compile step, it is significantly slower than the others.

Below is the code for the benchmark.  You will need to add ApacheCommonsLang to your classpath to run this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

/**
 *
 */
public class StringTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numIterations = 100000;
        int numRuns = 10;
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
          for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) strings.add("Remove the word remove from String "+i);
          //Your method
          long before = 0;
          long after = 0;
          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
                  for(String s : strings){
                      String newvalue = s.split(" ", 2)[1];
    //                System.out.println("split " + newvalue);
                  }
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("Split Took "+after + " ms");
          }


          // Substring method
          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
                  for(String s : strings){
                      String newvalue = s.substring(s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                  }
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("Substring Took "+after + " ms");
          }



          // Apache Commons Lang method
          before = System.currentTimeMillis();
          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
                  for (String s : strings) {
                      String parentStringValue = StringUtils.substringAfter(s, " ");
                  }
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("CommonsLang Took "+after + " ms");
          }


          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              long deleteTime = 0l;     
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){

                  List<StringBuilder> stringBuilders = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
                  for (String s : strings) {
                      stringBuilders.add(new StringBuilder(s));
                  }
                  long beforeDelete = System.currentTimeMillis();
                  for (StringBuilder s : stringBuilders) {
                      s.delete(0, s.indexOf(" ") + 1);
                  }
                  deleteTime+=(System.currentTimeMillis() - beforeDelete);
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("StringBuilder Delete " + deleteTime + " ms out of " + after + " total ms");
          }

          // Faster Regex method
          Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s");
          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
                  for (String s : strings) {
                      String newvalue = pattern.matcher(s).replaceFirst("");
                  }
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("Faster Regex Took "+after + " ms");
          }

          // Slow Regex method
          for(int j=0; j < numRuns; j++) {
              before = System.currentTimeMillis();
              for(int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++){
                  for (String s : strings) {
                      String newvalue = s.replaceFirst("\\w+\\s", "");
                  }
              }
              after = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;
              System.out.println("Slow Regex Took " + after + " ms");
          }

    }
}
```

On my machine with an I7 processor I got the following results:

```
Split Took 10552 ms
Split Took 10298 ms
Split Took 10297 ms
Split Took 10292 ms
Split Took 10527 ms
Split Took 10356 ms
Split Took 10324 ms
Split Took 10283 ms
Split Took 10375 ms
Split Took 10346 ms
Substring Took 2385 ms
Substring Took 2354 ms
Substring Took 2363 ms
Substring Took 2358 ms
Substring Took 2361 ms
Substring Took 2367 ms
Substring Took 2370 ms
Substring Took 2350 ms
Substring Took 2354 ms
Substring Took 2397 ms
CommonsLang Took 2462 ms
CommonsLang Took 2461 ms
CommonsLang Took 2422 ms
CommonsLang Took 2426 ms
CommonsLang Took 2479 ms
CommonsLang Took 2441 ms
CommonsLang Took 2440 ms
CommonsLang Took 2420 ms
CommonsLang Took 2418 ms
CommonsLang Took 2421 ms
StringBuilder Delete 2302 ms out of 5904 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2272 ms out of 5908 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2241 ms out of 5879 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2263 ms out of 5856 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2285 ms out of 5858 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2305 ms out of 5864 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2287 ms out of 5854 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2238 ms out of 5890 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2335 ms out of 5875 total ms
StringBuilder Delete 2301 ms out of 5863 total ms
Faster Regex Took 18387 ms
Faster Regex Took 18331 ms
Faster Regex Took 18421 ms
Faster Regex Took 18356 ms
Faster Regex Took 18297 ms
Faster Regex Took 18416 ms
Faster Regex Took 18338 ms
Faster Regex Took 18467 ms
Faster Regex Took 18326 ms
Faster Regex Took 18355 ms
Slow Regex Took 35748 ms
Slow Regex Took 35855 ms
Slow Regex Took 35924 ms
Slow Regex Took 35761 ms
Slow Regex Took 35764 ms
Slow Regex Took 35698 ms
Slow Regex Took 35646 ms
Slow Regex Took 35637 ms
Slow Regex Took 35871 ms
Slow Regex Took 35781 ms
```

Comment: +1 Well spotted, I threw that benchmark together far too quickly. The OP has accepted my answer so I will probably just go through and correct some of the mistakes. Otherwise I would get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adverse to using [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) then you could use the `StringUtils` class.

Would mean that you don't have to cater for String.indexOf returning -1:

```
String parentStringValue = StringUtils.substringAfter(yourString, " ");
```