# Pattern.split slower than String.split

Tags: java, regex, string, split

There are two methods:

```
private static void normalSplit(String base){
    base.split("\\.");
}

private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\.");

private static void patternSplit(String base){
    //use the static field above
    p.split(base);

}
```

And I test them like this in the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String longstr = "a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h.i.j";//use any long string you like
    for(int i=0;i<300000;i++){
        normalSplit(longstr);//switch to patternSplit to see the difference
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000.0);
}
```

Intuitively,I think as `String.split` will eventually call `Pattern.compile.split` (after a lot of extra work) to do the real thing. I can construct the Pattern object in advance (it is thread safe) and speed up the splitting.

But the fact is, using the pre-constructed Pattern is **much slower** than calling `String.split` directly. I tried a 50-character-long string on them (using MyEclipse), the direct call consumes only half the time of using pre-constructed Pattern object.

Please can someone tell me why this happens ?

Comment: Take a look at the source. It _does_ call `Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit)`, but only if the string to split by is more than a single character. At least in OpenJDK7, See [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html), line 2312.

Comment: @tobias_k Funny, you are the only one to point out that crucial detail ... in a comment, where all the other folks write up incomplete answers instead.

Comment: Loosely related answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26159501/2182928

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may depend on the actual implementation of Java. I'm using OpenJDK 7, and here, `String.split` does indeed invoke `Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit)`, but *only if* the string to split by, `regex`, is more than a single character.

See [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html) for the source code, line 2312.

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
   /* fastpath if the regex is a
      (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
         RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
      (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
         the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
   */
   char ch = 0;
   if (((regex.count == 1 &&
       // a bunch of other checks and lots of low-level code
       return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
   }
   return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

As you are splitting by `"\\."`, it is using the "fast path". That is, *if* you are using OpenJDK.

Comment: But `\\.` is actually a two-char string, am I wrong?

Comment: @sp00m See the comment: "(2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter."

Comment: My fault, you're right, that was actually implemented in the *bunch of other checks and lots of low-level code* :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the change in `String.split` behaviour, which was made in `Java 7`. This is what we [have](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java?av=f#2264) in `7u40`:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
        RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
        the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
    char ch = 0;
    if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
         ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
         (regex.length() == 2 &&
          regex.charAt(0) == '\\' &&
          (((ch = regex.charAt(1))-'0')|('9'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'a')|('z'-ch)) < 0 &&
          ((ch-'A')|('Z'-ch)) < 0)) &&
        (ch < Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE ||
         ch > Character.MAX_LOW_SURROGATE))
    {
        //do stuff
        return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
    }
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

And this is what we [had](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.split%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29) in `6-b14`

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can only be explained by JIT optimization, String.split internally does is implemented as follows:

```
Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
```

and it works faster when it is inside String.class, but when I use the same code in the test:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
        //base.split("\\.");// switch to patternSplit to see the difference
        //p.split(base);
        Pattern.compile("\\.").split(base, 0);
    }
```

I am getting the same result as `p.split(base)`